# What browser engine does Android Browser 4 use?

Tags: css

I see from my stats that Android Browser 4 comes up very high % wise in my browser reports.

Does Android Browser 4 use Blink as its engine or something else? If my site renders in Chrome fine on a desktop will it be OK in Android Browser 4?

Answer (score 1):

The android browser utilizes **WebKit** for rendering and **Google's V8** engine for JavaScript.

Yes, it will work. If I remember correctly there are some minor differences but generally it should work since Google Chrome also uses them.

Just remember that there are different versions of WebKit out there and Chrome usually updates pretty fast.

Comment: That may have been the case five years ago. http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4271

Comment: @Shikkediel sure, but he asked for the android web browser. Since 4 years Android use Chrome as their broswer

Comment: *New Webviews also share the same rendering engine as Chrome for Android...* https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview